# Paypal disable credit card button

Tags: android, paypal

I'm using the Paypal SDK in Android and I want to disable credit card payments. So the credit card button must be disabled.

I found solutions here on stackoverflow like:

```
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD, true);
```

the only problem is that PaymentActivity doesn't have that flag so it doesn't compile. 
I found this link:
http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PayPalConfiguration.html

and I thought I could solve it like this:

> intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,new
>   PayPalConfiguration().acceptCreditCards(false));

this compiles but it doesn't disable that button.

Comment: Why? Do you want to cut down your market?

Comment: Because the credit card isn't supported in Belgium. You can see the available countries here https://devblog.paypal.com/the-rest-api-is-going-global/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem you need to do this like:

```
PayPalConfiguration() object = new PayPalConfiguration();
object = object.acceptCreditCards(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

**It's Work for me **

```
public static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID).acceptCreditCards(false);
```